# How to create a generator of tuples whose values change at different times

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a generator where the tuple values will be coming from 2 lists. And what I intend is to run through all the values of the first list for each value of the second list. For instance, given these two lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
```

I want to get this:

```
((1,4), (2,4), (3,4), (1,5), (2,5), (3,5), (1,6), (2,6), (3,6))
```

What I tried as a test was:

```
parameters = ((value1, value2) for value1, value2 in zip(list1, list2))
```

But of course this does not give me what I want, so my question is how can I change `parameters` to get the output I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` as a variation on [@Gal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64624795/1126841).

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = [4,5,6]
>>> [(y, x) for x, y in product(list2, list1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 6)]
>>> tuple((y, x) for x, y in product(list2, list1))
((1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 6))
```

Comment: Thank you, I opted with your answer due to syntax and efficiency!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]

tuples = tuple([(first, second) for first in list1 for second in list2])
print(tuples)
```

Output:

```
((1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6))
```